# How do I get the text of a radio button (not the value)

Tags: javascript, dom, input

I know I can get the "value" attribute of a radiobutton but I'm finding it strangely difficult to get the text of the radiobutton.

Consider the example below.  It has 3 radiobuttons and tries to alert the value of the first radio button, which is "red" and then trys to alert the text of the radiobutton, "apple" but that fails.

Getting the text of almost any element can be done with elem.childNodes[0].nodeValue.  Why doesn't it work for radiobuttons?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" >
<head>
<title>Radio Buttons</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function start(){
  var rblist = document.getElementsByName("colors");
  var elem = rblist[0];
  alert(elem.value); // PRINTS "RED"
  alert(elem.childNodes[0].nodeValue); //THROWS ERROR
}
</script>       
</head>
<body onload="start();">
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="red" checked>apple</input>
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="blue">sky</input>
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="green">grass</input>
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't work because there is no such thing as text inside an `<input>` like that -- that's illegal in XHTML. It must be:

`<input type="radio" name="colors" value="red" id="radio1" checked="checked" /><label for="radio1">apple</label>`

Then you can look for the text inside the `<label>`.

Comment: +1 - 2nd time I've seen someone put text in an `<input>` element today, interesting

Comment: +1 - I admit I didn't even know it was possible. ;) First time I saw something like this. Nevertheless the value can be retrieved, anyway (see my answer).

Answer (score 4):

```
elem.nextSibling.nodeValue.replace('\n', '')
```

The replace is to get rid of the newline (may be different on different OSes, I am running Windows) character which is there for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id="myForm">
  <ul>
      <li><input type="radio" name="colors" value="red">apple</li>
      <li><input type="radio" name="colors" value="blue">sky</li>
      <li><input type="radio" name="colors" value="green">grass</li>
  </ul>
</form>

<script> 
(function(){
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");

    var colorFields = form.elements["colors"];

   alert(colorFields[0].nextSibling.data); //alerts the text apple not the value red. 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this answer because previously there was no full solution to the question.
Below code uses two prototype functions from the Array object:

1. `forEach` to add click event listener for each radio node
2. `filter` to retrieve checked radio node

as the RadioNodeList does not have those functionalities build-in.

```js
var rblist = document.getElementsByName("colors");;

[].forEach.call(rblist, function(e) {
  e.addEventListener('click', showText, false)
});

function showText() {
  var rb = [].filter.call(rblist, function(e) {
    return e.checked;
  })[0];
  console.log(rb.nextElementSibling.innerText);
};
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="red" /><label>apple</label>
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="blue" /><label>sky</label>
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="green" /><label>grass</label>
```