# How to get the text after a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Code:

```
<input type="radio" value="x" name="a" />One<br />
<input type="radio" value="y" name="b" />Two<br />
....
```

I have many of `radio` buttons like above.

How can I get text string after a `radio` when it has been clicked?

**EDITING HTML IS NOT POSSIBLE**

Comment: You really should be using a `label` around those. It's more accessible, and as a bonus will make your problem easier to solve.

Comment: @You I know that. But editing HTML not possible. Is there any other way? Help me with someone, Friend.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308509/how-do-i-get-the-text-of-a-radio-button-not-the-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use jQuery to grab the nextSibling data from that since the text is not part of the current input tag and isn't wrapped in any tags.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function(e) {
        var radioText = e.currentTarget.nextSibling.data
        alert(radioText);
    });
});
```

EDIT:
Little late for another edit but you could use labels or wrap your text in a p or span tag for making it easier to target with jQuery

```
<input type="radio" value="x" name="a" /><span>One</span><br />
<input type="radio" value="y" name="b" /><span>Two</span><br />

    (function(){
        var inputs = $('input[type=radio]');
        inputs.each(function(i, elm){
            console.log($(elm).next().html());
        })
    })();
```

You will see in the log the text of the span elements. (in the console)

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
var radioButtonNames = ["a", "b"];  // Add the names of your other radio buttons 
for (var i = 0; i < radioButtonNames.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(radioButtonNames[i]).onclick = function(){
        var result = this.nextSibling.data;
        alert(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That text belongs to the `<body>` tag or its closest parent.  I'd wrap the text in a `<span>` then do a `$(this).next('span').text()` inside your radio button's click event handler.

Comment: Why wrap it in a `span` when theres a perfectly good element designed for this very purpose (`label`)?

Comment: The point is it needs to be wrapped in an element if he wants to grab specific text.  HTML nazi...

Answer (score 0):

```
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined)
    if(radioObj.checked)
        return radioObj.value;
    else
        return "";
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    if(radioObj[i].checked) {
        return radioObj[i].value;
    }
}
```

this will get the radio object value out, then you can use the previous answer to pull the response into a  or div

---

Answer (score 0):

Please use `object.innerHTML` or `object.innerText` methods

In your case JS would be like.

```
var text = $('a').innerHTML;
```