# Populate form text field with button image

Tags: javascript, html, image, forms, button

I have seen this question/answer here [populate text box on click of radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930971/populate-text-box-on-click-of-radio-button)

That essentially achieves what i want, but instead of radio buttons i want to use my own images to use as buttons, so you click on the image "tag" and then it will grey out/ turn almost transparent and it will fill in the form field.

It is for a search form, so people can click on a button that says "restaurants" and then it will fill in the form field with restaurants, they can still type in the main search field if they want to but its just to guide users a bit more.

If there is any way we can do this without javascript then awesome, but i probably can't see that happening.

Hopefully its relatively simple.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what code do you have now?  What's not working with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KNct8/159/)!

Enjoy :)

**Html:**

```
 <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <div>
    <img class="stam" alt="Resturant" src="img1.jpg"/>

    <img class="stam" alt="Gym" src="img2.jpg"/>        

    </div>
</fieldset>       
<br>
<form>
    <input type="text">
</form>
```

**Js:**

```
$('.stam').on('click', function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').val($(this).attr("alt"));

});
```

Comment: downvote for using jQuery without saying so ;) Question states 'if possible no JS' so adding jQuery kind of adds a lot of bloat

Comment: Sorry for such a long time before a reply! It looks really good to me and the Fiddle seems to work perfectly too! I will test it out and let you know THANK YOU!

Comment: Now is there someone who can explain to me exactly whats happening here? like what the fieldset is for and the data types etc. thanks again :)

Comment: IT WORKED! had a bit of trouble because the CMS my company decided to use is SHOCKING but worked around it and its beautiful thank you. Another question, how to i make this unique to a single field, i will be having 3 fields, type of place ( this one) where (as in the city) and miles (radius from city) and i just want to populate the first search field.

Comment: To make it unique to a specific field i used #mycustomid instead of theinput[type="text"]

Comment: Another questions if possible... how do i put the images underneath the form? i tried to just move the fieldset but then nothing works...

Comment: You need to take all the <fieldset>-- bla bla --</fieldset> and all what inside of him!

Comment: Good luck, Have fun :)

Answer (score -1):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2JWD9/)

A few changes and you are good to go!

#### HTML

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
  <div id="img_filter">
    <img data-filter="Restaurant" src="http://placehold.it/120x30/&text=Restaurant"/>
    <img data-filter="Park" src="http://placehold.it/120x30/&text=Park"/>
    <img data-filter="Bank" src="http://placehold.it/120x30/&text=Bank"/>
  </div>
</fieldset>       
<form>
  <input id="query" type="text" />
</form>
```

#### JS

```
$('#img_filter img').on('click', function() {   
 $('#query').val($(this).data('filter'));
});
```