# populate field when press radio button java script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to populate fields with data from a table or a psql database . i tired to do it with javascript but i did not succeed .

my table is on the end of the code . in every line there is a radio button . i want to add an event to every button , when i click on it, it populate fields(4 inputs named : allee , retour , prix , nbpl) with data in the line .

this is a link to take a look over my code :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/maz80toz0an75g9/ajout_vol.php

i tried the solution on this link : 
[populate text box on click of radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930971/populate-text-box-on-click-of-radio-button)

but i don't know how use it to get all data from the table and populate fields .

Comment: You should include all relevant information regarding your problem in your question - or at least at some publicly accessible, rather persistent place. I don't have a Google account so you already lost one person who could potentially help you.

Comment: i change the link :D , it will be helpfull if you can see it

Comment: It's not really clear what it is you want. Could you be specific and explain what you want to happen when what radio is clicked based on what values? Your radio named idvol doesn't seem to have any event handlers that would do something on change and code for included script named main.js is missing. I've added jquery as a tag because I can see in the referenced code that you've included the jQuery library.